# Pivot control with XNA Assemblies

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, publish, xna-4.0, marketplace

Recently I developed an application using a Pivot control as a "menu" and other pages with XNA content (2D and 3D).

Now, I discovered that my application won't be certified cause Im using System.XNA.Framework.Game and System.XNA.Framework.Graphics in my app.

This is really upsetting me at the moment, cause it's throwing away hours of work...

I never published something on the marketplace, so I'm asking if it's possible, anyway, to publish an application of this kind or at least, publish it as Beta Testing without "Certification" as they say on few pages..

Any clue?

Comment: I could be wrong here - but wasn't that an old restriction? Pre-Mango update? What is your information source?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh184844(v=vs.92).aspx  point 4.2.5 The application must not call any APIs in the Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game assembly or the Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics assembly when using any methods from the System.Windows.Controls namespace.

I hope it's not a restriction for the beta. I got no idea..

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's out of date, given that [their own sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202938%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) (and project template) breaks that rule. But I'll let an actual WP7 developer provide a definitive answer for you. Surely someone has a Silverlight + XNA app up on the store? That was a big thing for Mango.

Comment: indeed, yes , but i know that if i use a xna/silverlight applications than i have some assemblies that Pivot control is using which are disallowed..http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Silverlight-vs-XNA-and-using-them-together  for example...but it's really out-dated... and it's not really clear from Microsoft

Answer (score 1):

Composite Silverlight+XNA applications are different from full-featured Silverlight applications invoking XNA assemblies. The restriction is still there - you must not have calls to **Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game** or **Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics**.

Mind you, some XNA elements are still allowed, such as **Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio**, that gives you access to the [Microphone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.audio.microphone.aspx) class, or **Microsoft.Xna.Framework**, that lets you access the [FrameworkDispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.frameworkdispatcher.update.aspx).